# notifyItemInserted renders the entire list again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have the following method -

```kotlin
  private fun initRoomObserving() {
        dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
        dashboardViewModel.getAllMessagesEntities().observe(this, Observer { receivedMessageList ->
            receivedMessageList.forEach {
                if (!userPhoneNumber.equals(it.senderUsername)) {
                    it.isReceiver = true
                }
                if (!messagesList.contains(it)) {
                    messagesList.add(it)
                }
            }
            conversationAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messagesList.size)
            conversationAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(messagesList.size - 1,messagesList.size)

        })
    }
```

For some reason the entire list is being rendered again for each time a new entity is beining added, even though I am explicitly `notifyItemInserted` and not `notifyDataSetChanged`

Why is this happening and what am I missing?

Comment: try `conversationAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(messagesList.size - 1,/*numberOfNewItems*/ someCount)`

Comment: Number of new items is always 1, and what is 'some count'?

Comment: then `someCount` should be `1`

Comment: solved, please comment and I will approve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seconds parameter for `notifyItemRangeChanged` takes the count as value so since the value of changes item is always one so pass `1` instead of `messagesList.size` as:

```
conversationAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(messagesList.size - 1, 1)
```

Additionally, [someCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368975/notifyiteminserted-renders-the-entire-list-again?noredirect=1#comment108564682_61368975) can be variable which can track the number of changed items which can be used for `notifyItemRangeChanged` when you will have more then one item for updates.